# How do I port device drivers, in Windows, from x86 to ARM?

Tags: windows, arm, port, x86-64, driver

I'm on a project that was originally made for the **x86_64** platform, with **Windows**, in C/C++ languages. This project is now being ported to **ARM**, still on Windows OS.

This project accesses devices, such as keyboard, mouse, sound, and so on, and these devices are accessed through drivers. So we want to **port some drivers used in x86_64 to ARM**. However, in x86_64 device access is very different than ARM, as we all know:

- In x86_64 is through I/O ports mapped in memory, outside the address
  space.
- In ARM through the peripheral controller registers, mapped in a
  memory space within the address space.

The question is: **how do we port the driver from x86_64 to ARM, in the Windows kernel**? That is, **how do we access devices on ARM, on Windows**, such as a simple GPIO, a sound device, a keyboard, etc?

Thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: WDM? KMDF? Why are you accessing these devices from a driver?

Comment: USB keyboards/mice are accessed through USB controllers, so they'll use modern MMIO (at the lowest level in the USB stack).  Only legacy PS/2 mouse/keyboard controllers use `in`/`out` port-IO.  Same for sound; maybe some legacy sound cards like SoundBlaster16 used some I/O ports, but modern controllers are PCI / PCIe devices with their IO registers in PCIe memory regions.

Comment: e.g. according to `lspci -v` on my Linux system, the chipset's Intel HD Audio Controller is at  `Memory at f7240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]` / `Memory at f7220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]`.  Those addresses aren't hard-coded, they're just what PCIe autoconfig picked. (And that device is capable of bus-mastering, so it can DMA sound data from RAM)

Comment: The way you access a register (port mapped vs memory mapped) is a relatively small and easy detail to abstract. If anything else is the same, you define a few HAL functions. In fact, Windows should already have them.